# New to C#, unable to update variable in for loop

Tags: c#, for-loop

I am about 2 hours into learning C# (and programing in general) at the time of writing this and I am trying to write a simple program to help my son learn to add two-digit numbers together. What I have is

```
//Creating needed variables    
using System.Data.Common;

int num1, num2, answer, numCorrect, numIncorrect, question;
String userAnswer;
Random random = new Random();
numCorrect = 0;
numIncorrect = 0;

//Looping the question for 10 rounds
for (question = 0; question < 11; question++)
{
    //Defining Numbers
    ;
    num1 = random.Next(1, 100);
    num2 = random.Next(1, 100); 

    //The Problem
    Console.WriteLine(num1 + "+" + num2 + "= ?");
    userAnswer = Console.ReadLine();
    answer = Convert.ToInt32(userAnswer);

    //Logic that will provide the ansewer.
    if (answer == (num1 + num2))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Correct, ");
        numCorrect = numCorrect++;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Incorrect, ");
        numIncorrect = numIncorrect++;
    }
    Console.Write("You have " + numCorrect + " Correct and " + numIncorrect + " Incorrect");
}
```

Whether correct or not, the outcome is the same. It will always return:

"You have 0 Correct and 0 Incorrect"

I am unsure what I am doing wrong and why it is not updating the value for numCorrect and numIncorrect. I have attempted to have the variables initialize both inside and outside the for loop. Any Thoughts?

Comment: You're overwriting the variable with the value _before_ incrementing the variable, i.e. 0. Omit the `foo =`, because the `++` operator increments the variable by itself.

Comment: `numIncorrect = numIncorrect++;` -> `numIncorrect++;`

Comment: See [postfix increment operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#postfix-increment-operator)

Comment: OT with `question<11` you are going 11 times through the loop, not 10 (because you start at 0)

Answer (score 5):

You are assigning and incrementing numCurrect and numIncurrect variable.
you only need to do is increment

```
 if (answer == (num1 + num2))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Correct, ");
        numCorrect++;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Incorrect, ");
        numIncorrect++;
    }
```

reason :
you are doing post-increment it returns the old value and then updates the value after so what's happening is it increases the value by 1 but while assigning it sets it to the old value (that is 0) so it never gets updated.

Hope that helps